# Name of the rule about access to members

Tags: language-agnostic

I am getting old, hence I am unable to recall the name of the rule that says (loosely) that a method of a class should mess only with its arguments, or the instance itself.

Comment: @Alex: +1 internets to you. :-D

Comment: @Doyle : today it's called intertubes. Didn't you get the memo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)?

I don't think it was created by the Greek goddess of the harvest, though... :-)